# How do I blur with shader nodes?

Tags: shaders

How do I achieve a blur on an image texture (or any color output) with shader nodes?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any node that automatically blurs a texture (it would be nice, it would allow to easily tweak a height map from any picture), that said Decoded explains [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBwydfiqSas) how you can do it with this node setup: Plug your *Texture Coordinate* into a *Noise Texture* with *Roughness* at 1 and high *Detail* and *Distortion*, then plug into 2 *Color > MixRGB*, one in *Subtract* mode, the other in *Add* mode, and at last plug into your texture:

[image]

Comment: how did you get the noodles to be colored in this way at either end?

Comment: I guess it was in this Blender version?

Answer (score 2):

@moonboots's answer didn't look quite right for me. I added a distance node and that really helped. I also made the blur amount configurable by using a multiply node. If you want to blur in different directions, use the whole vector instead of XYZ being one value like I did.

[image]

Comment: Do you know about the vector math scale node?

Comment: @Leander haha yes, don't know why I did it the hard way. Updated the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily blur an image texture with OSL:

```
shader BlurImage(
vector UV = vector(u,v,0),
string Filename = "",
string WrapMode = "periodic"
//wrapmodes: black, clamp, periodic, mirror
float BlurFactor = 0,
//BlurFactor is a coeficient relative to image size (0.1 = 10% blur)
output color Color = 0,
)
{
Color = texture(Filename, UV[0], 1.0-UV[1], "wrap", WrapMode, "blur", BlurFactor);
}
```

[image]

In the above image, the BlurFactor is parametrized as an Object Custom property to compare the effect of different values.

This is for image files, for other blurring you better use the noise distortion method.