# Blurring and moving an HDRI background

Tags: hdri

By following some YouTube videos I have added an HDR image to serve as a background to my 3D model of a stone circle, but not only do I need to blur and soften it but also shift the image to show more of the sky. I have tried to follow other videos to do this but some of the functions have been moved in the 3.1 version so I'm lost.

I include a grab of where I am at so far and the background image inserted. I have tried some depth of field changes but they did not show.

[image: HDRI in background]

[image: HDR image]

Comment: here is a way to blur but I don't know if it will fit your needs: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258728/how-do-i-blur-with-shader-nodes/258734#258734 maybe you should simply rework your image in an image editor?

Comment: Related: [How to blur a texture node in cycles material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9394/78972)

Comment: Hi :). To move/rotate the HDRI, simply use the Mapping node

Comment: i would recommend installing the free "easy HDRI" for this. Just search on google for "blender easy hdri download" -> then you move and adjust your HDRI like a boss :D [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqPoS.gif

Answer (score 1):

you could blur the background with 2 scenes, one with HDRI, one without like this:

[image]

So one scene hast just the background, then in compositor you blur it and the other scene has the objects and "transparent" checked in the render settings.

You could rotate your HDRI with Easy HDRI add-on (free) or as Jachym said, just use the mapping node.

Comment: Not sure what all that means but I guess I’ll find out with some experimentation 

Comment: I have added a panoramic image of my own (not 360) but it does not show at all. Why is that?

Comment: pls ask new/other question as new questions, not as comments. You may open as many questions as you want.